# PHP Insert String value with Special characters

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing Android application and I am trying to insert some data to mysql database, one of the columns is storing the name of the gps location,I read values like this ("Alfa Gas Station"), but when I read unknown place the value become like this (29°17'37.3"N 47°52'23.4"E) and when I try to save it, the php code returns Not registered as shown in my code and I want to save it in my database in this form. when I tried the solution of in this link to prevent SQL-Injection [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) , It prevent the insertion process but this is not what do I want, I want the code insert the string value whatever it was consisting of, because this value is generated from google map not written by users so it can't be harmful, so I wish anyone can help me:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
       require "init.php";
       creat_Student();
}
function creat_Student()
{
    global $con;
    $id=$_POST["id"];
    $lat=$_POST["lat"];
    $long=$_POST["long"];
    $price=$_POST["price"];
    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $address=$_POST["address"];
    $status=$_POST["status"];                             
    $query="INSERT INTO  parking (`userid`, `lat`, `long`, `price`, `name`, `address`, `status`) VALUES ('$id','$lat','$long','$price', '$name','$address','$status');";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
    echo "Successfully Registered";
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "Not registered";
    }
    mysqli_close($con); 
}
```

It works well but it didn't work when it is unknown place , and the name column in my database is `400 Varchar`

Comment: what error in the log file?

Comment: I bet the `'` is the problem. Escape the string first, or - better - use prepared statements.